# Using a colon with named arguments in ColdFusion

Tags: syntax, coldfusion

I saw this code example in a recording and wanted to know what the colon syntax did. I searched the docs, but I wasn't able to find any info on it:

`weather.subscribe(observer: application.observers.currentConditions);`

I know we can use colon in CF9 for ternary operators:

`result = (condition) ? true : false;`

But in this case it looks like it's being used to provide named arguments; so what's it doing there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `<cfset result = obj.func(arg:value,thing:42) />` I looked at this and
>   went *blink, blink*... That can't be right! You can't use colons for
>   named arguments! Er, can you? Well, apparently you can.

http://corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/Learn_something_new_every_day_named_arguments

Comment: Who cannot believe it, you or Sean? ;)

Comment: Yipes, that is actually the "quote" style on SO? Its nearly indistinguishable from regular text :/ No wonder I blinked twice ...

Comment: @Leigh, I think your LCD has some colour calibration issues :D -- on one of my laptops I also find it difficult to see the background color.

Comment: @Mohmamad - Duh! You are right. On another machine it is much more pronounced. On this one I can only see it if I squint real hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are allowed to use both. I think it's a matter of preference. You can even mix.

Try this and see, mocked up some test function:

```
<cffunction name="testFunction" returntype="void" hint="I just spit out the arguments I get">
    <cfdump var="#arguments#" label="arguments">
</cffunction>

<cfset testFunction(arg1:"hello",arg2:"world") />
<cfset testFunction(arg1="hello",arg2="world") />
<cfset testFunction(arg1:"I can mix",arg2="my named argument syntax") />
```

Personally, I prefer = for named arguments. You might also notice that if you use IntelliJ IDEA for your ColdFusion development that they do not recognize the colon syntax, so for better parsing you would want to use the = syntax. I can't speak for other IDEs

Comment: CFEclipse doesn't have the same bug as IntelliJ IDEA, and I doubt CFBuilder does either.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a typo to me.  In ColdFusion you would use an equals sign (`=`) not a colon to used named arguments.

Your example would become:

```
weather.subscribe(observer = application.observers.currentConditions);
```

Comment: @Sean Coyne, I don't think it is a typo. There were several examples that used the same format, and someone commented about it being a cool thing (that colons work). What I'm trying to understand is what is the syntax means. Is it just another way of saying `arg=myValue`?

Comment: I've seen colon work for named arg in CF, but yes, = is what everybody uses.

Comment: @Henry, so it's just another way of saying `doSomething(myArg = myValue)` ?