# Setting variables and values inside a cfset statement in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I was reviewing some code today and ran across some syntax I hadn't seen used quite like this before. As such, I couldn't Google it because I don't know how to refer to it in "tech speak".

Given this hypotethectical situation, what is the part inside of the ( ) called? I understand WHAT is happening, I just don't know what it is called other than "setting a variable before passing the value to the CFC".   :)

```
<cfset inputHelper.validatePasswordRules( 
    password: form.password, 
    passwordConfirmed: form.confirmPassword
) />
```

In the CFC itself, the cfarguments would be password and passwordConfirmed. For example,

```
<cfargument name="password" type="string" required="true" />
<cfargument name="passwordConfirmed" type="string" required="true" />
```

I'm not sure why the call to the CFC isn't just:

```
<cfset inputHelper.validatePasswordRules( form.password, form.confirmPassword ) />
```

unless the two cfset statements are essentially the same thing?

Comment: (Edit) It is another way of [invoking a function with named arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653677/using-a-colon-with-named-arguments-in-coldfusion). The two example are similar, but the latter syntax relies on positional notation, so you cannot skip arguments ie `someFunction(arg1='yyyy',arg3='xxx')` BTW, unless you have other questions about it, I am going to vote to close as a duplicate :)

Comment: @Leigh You answered my question so thank you. You may close it. Also, thank you for the link that was helpful.

Comment: Okay, cool. I know what you mean about search terms. Hard to find something, when you do not what it is called ;-)